# Adjusting text in html/css portfolio website project

Tags: html, css

I am attemping to move title "data analyst" to be centered in this piece of code.. I'm not sure why it's not already as code is labeled center in the .front-person-titles > span piece of css. I am very new to css/html (just started working on this portfolio webpage a few days ago.) Where in these lines of css would I change the code so that data analayst text is centered?? In addition to this, when I run code snippet in stackoverflow, the image is formatted the same as the gray box from .front-person-img css code and NOT from the .front-person-img > img code. I am not sure how to make the image respond to the > img code so that its formatting is separate as seen in this jpeg. [image: normal image postion]

Thank you!

```css
.front-section {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
  position: relative;
}


}
.section-block>.container,
.section-block {
  position: relative;
}

/*=======================================================================
    Front Section
=======================================================================*/
body.section-show .transition-mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 260px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 22;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: fill2 .8s .4s both ease;
  -moz-animation: fill2 .8s .4s both ease;
  animation: fill2 .8s .4s both ease;
}
body .transition-mask:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body.section-show .transition-mask:before {
  -webkit-animation: fill .4s both ease;
  -moz-animation: fill .4s both ease;
  animation: fill .4s both ease;
  background: #CCC;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fill2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  
  100% {
    z-index: 50;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: auto;
  }
}
@keyframes fill2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  
  100% {
    z-index: 50;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: auto;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fill {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes fill {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.front-section {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.front-heading {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 190px;
}
.front-heading>h2 {
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  letter-spacing: 15px;
  position: relative;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
  z-index: 10;
  color: #999;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-style: italic;
}
.front-person-img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 15;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s .3s ease, transform .5s .8s ease;
  -moz-transition: height .5s .3s ease, transform .5s .8s ease;
  transition: height .5s .3s ease, transform .5s .8s ease;
  margin: 200px auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-radius: 0;
}
.front-person-img > img {
  max-width: 100%;
  left: -40px;
  top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.front-person-titles {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -500px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.front-person-titles>span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Hind, sans-serif;
  color: #CCC;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 25px;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
.front-person-titles>.t1 {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-100%);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-100%);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-100%);
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-100%);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -o-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
.front-person-titles>.t2 {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
.front-person-titles>.t3 {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 5px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%) rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(100%) rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(100%) rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: translateY(100%) rotate(180deg);
  transform: translateY(100%) rotate(180deg);
}
.front-person-links {
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: -500px;
  z-index: 25;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
}
.front-person-links>ul>li {
  display: block;
}
.front-person-links>ul {
  font-size: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.front-person-links>ul>li>a {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 25px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  position: relative;
  color: #999;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.front-person-links>ul>li>a:before,
.front-person-links>ul>li>a:after {
  content: ' ';
  height: 6px;
  width: 15px;
  background: #CCC;
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-size: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  display: none;
}
.front-person-links>ul>li>a:after {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 0;
  display: none;
}
.front-person-links>ul>li>a:hover {
  color: #B7A389;
}
.front-person-links>ul>li>a:hover:after,
.front-person-links>ul>li>a:hover:before {
  width: 25px;
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<!--=============================================================================
                Front Section
            ===============================================================================-->
<section class='front-section'>

  <div class='container'>


    <div class='transition-mask'></div>


    <div class='front-person-img'>

      <!--person's image-->
     <a href="https://ibb.co/JjxQC0Y"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/qY05xXH/IMG-5876.jpg" alt="IMG-5876" border="0"></a>
      <!--/person's image-->

    </div>

    <!--person's titles-->
    <div class='front-person-titles'>

      <!--title1-->
      <span class='t1'>
                            Data Analyst
                        </span>
      <!--/title1-->

      <!--title2-->
      <span class='t2'>
                            Student
                        </span>
      <!--/title2-->

      <!--title3-->
      <span class='t3'>
                            
                        </span>
      <!--/title3-->

    </div>
```

Comment: Wrap all inline code in grave marks ` `.class > span` ` If you want to display a block of code but don't need it as a working example (with the two buttons) then wrap code three grave marks. Also, there's a button labeled 'tidy' in the code editor please use it to format your code.

Comment: What do you mean display a block of code but don't need it as a working example "the two buttons"? do you mean the html/css code snippet tool

Comment: @zer00ne are you talking about my html code or css code? .. I edited my code snippet and ran the tidy function. thanks

Comment: Okay so essentially what you want me to do is within the html code wrap all inline code with grave marks, then if I want the code there but do not need it displayed then wrap it in three grave marks. After that use tidy function @zer00ne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it looking how you want by modifying the `.front-person-titles>.t1` code to the following:

```css
.front-person-titles>.t1 {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-100%) translateX(-7.5%);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-100%) translateX(-7.5%);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-100%) translateX(-7.5%);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-100%) translateX(-7.5%);
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-100%) translateX(-7.5%);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -o-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

You can see a working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ajmeese7/sjwL375g/1/).

Comment: do you know why the image is showing up rotated in the code snippet in OP?

Comment: And what do you mean, do you want the image to be straight like it is now or do you want it to be diagonal @Stackstudent_09

Comment: Okay, I accepted it as answer. In the code snippet in original post my image is coming up diagonal but it is the same code (minus the new x translation) that you have in your JSfiddle.

Comment: @Stackstudent_09 you can manipulate the `.front-person-img img` selector and remove the transform if you don't want the rotation applied as it was in the question's picture :)

Comment: Hmmm that did not seem to work? I changed the code in the snippet